If $T^2$ has an upper-triangular matrix then $T$ has.
Is this question true:
Prove or give a counterexample: If $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $T^2$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V,$ then $T$ has an upper-triangular matrix with respect to some basis of $V.$
My gut feeling is yes but I do not know how to prove it.
My thoughts:
Since $T^2$ has an upper-triangular matrix, then assume that $\lambda_1^2, \dots, \lambda_n^2$ are its diagonal entries. Then $$(T^2 - (\lambda_1 I)^2)\dots(T^2 - (\lambda_n I)^2) = 0.$$
Do I have then to turn this into a polynomial and to factorize as difference between 2 squares or not?
I know also that by the given we know the form of the minimal polynomial of $T^2$ which is $$(z - \lambda_1^2)\dots (z - \lambda_n^2)$$ for some $\lambda_1^2 , \dots, \lambda_n^2.$
I also know that the square of an upper triangular matrix is still an upper triangular matrix (I am not sure if this is always correct, I tried it only for one upper triangular matrix and it worked).
Can someone clarify the solution of this problem to me please?

Is $V$ a vector space over a specific field (e.g., over $\mathbb{C}$) or are you asking if it is true for an arbitrary field?

no @noam.szyfer in the book it is usually $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$ . I know the statement on C is correct

This is not true for a very simple reason: $T^2$ has an eigenvalue doesn't imply $T$ has one. For example, take any matrix $A$ over $\mathbb R$ such that $A^2=-I$, then the eigenvalues of $A$ must be $\pm i\not\in\mathbb R$. Concretely, $A$ could be
$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
